# How can I create recyclerview in the form of Gridview?

Tags: android

I want to add images in gridview. can I create recyclerview in gridview form? If I can, then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Here is an [example](https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)